# How to use tee to append to start of file, as opposed to last?

Tags: bash, tee

I'm using this bash command to append data to a markdown file:
`echo "${{ env.PR_TITLE }}" | tee -a page1.md`.

I was wondering if I could append the echo statement to `page1.md` at the start, so line 1. As opposed to the last line.

If so how can I edit my command above to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with `tee` -- tee can only overwrite or append.

[ed](/questions/tagged/ed) is appropriate for this job: given file "page1.md":

```
This is the old first line.
This is the old second line.
```

Then the command

```bash
ed page1.md <<'END_ED'
1i
${{ env.PR_TITLE }}
.
wq
END_ED
```

results in

```
$ cat page1.md
${{ env.PR_TITLE }}
This is the old first line.
This is the old second line.
```

heredoc explained:

- `1i` - insert before line 1
- `${{ env.PR_TITLE }}` - the literal text to insert
- `.` - end inserting
- `wq` - save and quit

The equivalent [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```bash
sed -i '1i\
${{ env.PR_TITLE }}
' page1.md
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like

```
echo "\${{ env.PR_TITLE }}" | cat - page1.md > Tmp; mv Tmp page1.md
```

Check file attributes after the `mv`.